# Gradle exec task fails with “execCommand == null!”

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I'm trying to create a version bumper and tag creator on my build.gradle.kts, but I'm getting this error, can anyone help me ? Thanks!

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':gitTag'.
> execCommand == null!
```

My build.gradle.kts

```
tasks {
    val gitIsDirty by registering(Exec::class) {
        description = "Fails if git has uncommitted changes."
        group = "verification"
        commandLine("git", "diff", "--quiet", "--exit-code")
    }

    val gitTag by registering(Exec::class) {
        description = "Tags the local repository with version ${project.version}"
        group = PublishingPlugin.PUBLISH_TASK_GROUP
        dependsOn(gitIsDirty)
        if (isRelease) {
            commandLine("git", "commit", "-am", "Publishing version ${project.version}")
            commandLine("git", "tag", "-a", project.version, "-m", "Version ${project.version}")
            commandLine("git", "push", "origin", "${project.version}")
        }
    }

    val publishLocalMajor by registering(Exec::class) {
        group = PublishingPlugin.PUBLISH_TASK_GROUP
        dependsOn(incrementMajor, gitTag,publishToMavenLocal)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you write `commandLine()` without `if (isRelease)` condition?

Comment: Yes, this is the var  ```var isRelease = "release" in gradle.startParameter.taskNames```